# Where could I get the Torch Chess Game Installer for Windows 11?

Tags: engines, software

The question:
Where could I either buy or download Torch Chess Engine, please?
This to install it on my ever offline Laptop.

I do not like Stockfish, I prefer a more complex, nastier one, which thinks and acts outside the box.
And from what I gather, from YouTube videos on the subject, Torch is precisely this.

Comment: Torch is only available on chess.com. If you don't like SF, try Lc0.

Comment: You can also look at Dragon and Leela for more variant ideas.

Comment: Isn't Leela lc0?

Answer (score 5):

> Where could I get the Torch Chess Game Installer for Windows 11?

You can't and Chess.com have no plans to sell it. You can use it online for analysis or play against it online as a bot.

Here is what [Chess.com](https://www.chess.com/news/view/torch-chess-engine) said about it last July (2023) when it was launched

> Torch is not yet publicly available but will be made available to certain relevant third parties for ratings. It will also be available through Chess.com’s analysis in the future. The team hopes to bring new ideas to the engine to allow greater insights to be delivered to the chess community.

Comment: I suspect they have no reason to make it offline because having it play online will also give them data to improve it.